# WinForms data binding to a custom property throws an exception

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am sorry if this is a duplicate, but I searched the net and haven't found an answer

I am trying to bind the control's `Enabled` (or `ReadOnly` for `TextBox`):

```
this.tbProj.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", this, "CanEdit", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, false));
this.btnSave.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", this, "Dirty", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, false));
```

To the following properties:

```
public bool Dirty { get; set; }

private bool CanEdit
{
    get { return this._CurrentRecord.CanEdit(); }
}
```

I get `System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the property or column CanEdit on the DataSource.` when trying to `ShowDialog()` the form.

If I bind the `Enabled` or `ReadOnly` to `Dirty`, everything forks fine. I tried `get { return true; }` and even added a setter: `set { bool bummy=value; }`, same error. I even changed `CanEdit` to an auto-implemented property, same as `Dirty` (just `get; set;` in declaration) at no avail...

Please help.

Thanks for any hints and advice.

Comment: Any reason the property `CanEdit` has to be `private`? did you mean it to be `public`?

Comment: The `Record` class has extension methods that perform the same thing, so `private` was intended. In fact, all this property is doing is calling the extension method of the `_CurrentRecord` object. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property has to be public:

```
public bool CanEdit
{
    get { return this._CurrentRecord.CanEdit(); }
}
```

Comment: Why couldn't M$ put that explanation in the exception message? Thanks, all worked like a charm.